# How Can I implement custom authentication in django for user login

Tags: django, authentication

I want to implement custom login authentication in Django. I do not want to use Django's inbuilt authentication system because it is not working. I have a model named Doctor and I want to fetch the data from the Doctor model for login authentication. I have set my default database as MySQl database.

I have tried some code but it didn't work for me.

views.py

```
def login(request):
    if request.POST:
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request,user)
            return render(request,'welcome1.html') #success
        else: #Invalid login
            return render(request, 'login.html',{
                'error_message':'Invalid Credential'
            })
    return render(request, 'login.html')
```

models.py

```
class Doctor(models.Model):
    initial_name = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    hospital_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    username = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    dob = models.DateField(max_length=8)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    phone_number = models.TextField(max_length=10)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.initial_name
```

My expected output should be "when I will put wrong Email & password, it will show an error"
But it is automatically redirecting to my home page, if i put wrong eail or password.

Comment: Don't do this. You are storing the password in plain text, which is insecure. Use Django's built in authentication. If it's 'not working', then ask a question about that with as much information as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You hand better extend standard user model via AbstractUser

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project

if you want to have more specific fields such as hospital_name , etc in your user model